# User badge begins to walk when hovering over tags to edit

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just came across a bug in the edit tags hoverover, where after 4 hover in/out's, the users badge begins to walk on the screen.

Verified on

- Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
- Version 10.1 (12603.1.30.0.34)

Could not reproduce

- Firefox Version 53.0.2 (64-bit)

See Gif:

[image]

Comment: Noticed the same today (on Chrome as well)